# How to correctly poll raw fd in Rust?

Tags: sockets, networking, rust

I'm building a simple client/server in Rust. My project is working with raw sockets and my skeleton server looks like this:

```
    loop {
        let mut buf = vec![0; 1504];
        let connection_res = server.accept(&mut buf).await;
        tokio::spawn(async move {
            match connection_res {
                Ok(conn) => process(conn).await,
                Err(err) => eprintln!("Connection attempt failed: {:?}", err),
            }
        });
    }

    pub async fn accept(&mut self, buf: &mut [u8]) -> Result<Connection, ()> {
        let mut f = unsafe { File::from_raw_fd(self.raw_fd) };
        let _ = f.read(buf);

        let id = Alphanumeric.sample_string(&mut rand::thread_rng(), 16);

        // Build new connection handle
        let mut connection = Connection::new(id);
        connection.set_bytes_in(buf.into());

        // Could not parse connection; fail here.
        if let Err(_) = self.parse_and_set_header_info(buf, &mut connection) {
            return Err(());
        }

        // Update connection count
        self.num_connections += 1;

        Ok(connection)
    }
```

I'm able to receive packets over the network through a tun/tap interface. The problem is that the accept function is not being polled correctly and it keeps executing even after the 'real' data is flushed out of the buffer. This means that my `accept` function keeps reading in a buffer full of zeros.

I think the problem is that I'm not polling on the `read()` function. I would like for `accept()` to continue execution when there is new data in the raw socket otherwise, I would like to yield asynchronously. What is the Rust way/crates that I can use to do this?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Rust; There are no buffers full of zeroes in sockets; did you check how many bytes were *actually read*? It looks like you're completely ignoring how many bytes were read (`let _ = f.read(...)`)

Comment: In my server example, I always initialise the buffer to `vec![0; 1504]` (first line in loop). This is the buffer of all zeros. What I think is happening is that `f.read()` is just reading all the way to some eof. But I also think that the read() is always reading the fd, even if there is no new data. That's why I think the function is always getting executed and the buffer is then all zeros.

Comment: is that because you set it to non-blocking mode? did you set it to non-blocking mode?

Comment: `f.read` may read fewer bytes than requested. It returns a `Result<usize>` that tells you if an error occured and how many bytes were actually read. In case of `EOF` `f.read` will return `Ok(0)`, and if your socket is non-blocking and there is no data it will return `Err(e)` with `e.kind() == ErrorKind::WouldBlock`. But you need to check the returned value to see how many bytes were really read and whether an error occured.

Comment: Why are you using raw FDs and not something like [tokio-tun](https://docs.rs/tokio-tun/0.7.0/tokio_tun/)?